# How to create a pivot table in pandas for this example?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have data in the following format for which I would like to create a pivot table using pandas.

```
AGE        Good_Bad
(30, 45]    Good
(30, 45]    Good
(20, 30]    Bad
(60, 100]   Good
(30, 45]    Bad
```

The age column was generated by binning the Age variable using `pd.cut()`. My goal is to draw a summary of the `Good`s and the `Bad`s for each age group using a pivot table.

```
AGE    
           Good    Bad
(20, 30]    0       1
(60, 100]   1       0
(30, 45]    2       1
```

It is clear that my `index='AGE', columns='Good_Bad', values=count of 'Good_Bad'`. However, when I put that in the following form, I get a key error:

```
df_age.pivot_table(index = 'AGE', columns = 'Good_Bad', values = 'Good_Bad', aggfunc='count')
```

So far, I have been able to solve this using the groupby function and using Google sheets but even after trying out several things, it doesn't work with df.pivot_table().

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pd.crosstab(df.AGE,df.Good_Bad)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about crosstab. But why isn't pivot_table working?